# How to get TLS Session Id from a NGINX proxy?

Tags: node.js, nginx, tls1.2

In Node.js, headers are available in req.headers and I do get them in the http server.
I want to get the TLS session id set by the Nginx proxy where the setting, among other headers, in the relevant section, is:

```
location / {
...
proxy_set_header X-tlsSessionId $ssl_session_id;
...
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
 proxy_buffering off;
 expires off;

}
```

I am able to get access to other custom header but not to X-tlsSessionId when I try to access it as req.headers[x-tlssessionid] 
I think that the lowercase is what I use to get access to custom headers but this one does not work.

Comment: You can try `console.log(req.headers)` to see all headers sent to your server

Comment: @slebetman Sorry for the late comment. That header is not there in the req.headers. I did console.log in the servers. I see other headers though.

Comment: session ID is part of TLS packet wrapping over entire HTTP response / request,  so it is impossible to get it from HTTP header (I don't know about node.js but `req` may be http request not TLS request ?)